# Infinite button animation in Android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to make the button rotate forever, right after pressing it.
But it doesn't work

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);





    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button2.setClickable(false);
            while(true) {
                button2.setRotation(button2.getRotation() + 1);

            }
        }
    });
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press a button, it will be rotated infinitely.

**rotate.xml (res > anim > rotate.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <rotate
        android:duration="500"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

**Your Button Listener**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.rotate);
     animation.setFillAfter(true);
     btn.startAnimation(animation);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code on click

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(
            0, 360, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
        );
        rotate.setDuration(ROTATE_ANIMATION_DURATION);
        rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        button2.startAnimation(rotate);
```